# getting null exception for prepared statement in java

Tags: java, sql

This is the code  here i am trying to put some values to database using prepared statement but getting this null exception.

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt1 = null;
for(int index2=0;index2<3;index2++)
{
  for(int index1=0;index1<5;index1++)
  {   
     String tt = "INSERT INTO   timetable(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";
     stmt = con.prepareStatement(tt);
     stmt1.setInt(index1+1,index1*index2);
  }
  int success = 2;
  success = stmt1.executeUpdate();
 }
```

Comment: You are initializing `stmt` and `stmt1` is still NULL

Comment: Did you leave your spectacles at home this morning Ajay?  Anyway, you've got your answer, so I'm voting to close as "too localized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pull your Statement out off the loop, otherwise you keep creating a new prepared statement where only one parameter out of five is set:

Change your code:

```
for(int index1=0;index1<5;index1++)
{   
    String tt="INSERT INTO   timetable(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";
    stmt=con.prepareStatement(tt);
    stmt1.setInt(index1+1,index1*index2);
}
```

to

```
String tt="INSERT INTO   timetable(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";
stmt1=con.prepareStatement(tt);

for(int index1=0;index1<5;index1++)
{   
    stmt1.setInt(index1+1,index1*index2);
}
```

Comment: gr8>>>>>>> woking thaks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Here

```
stmt=con.prepareStatement(tt); // use stmt1 instead of stmt
stmt1.setInt(index1+1,index1*index2);// this is NULL
```

in the above line you initialized `stmt`

Comment: argh, you were fast. +1

Comment: now getting like this Exception: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: that's a different question. You should validate Apurv's answer for THIS question.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize **stmt1**, it's still null.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
stmt1=con.prepareStatement(tt);
stmt1.setInt(index1+1,index1*index2);
```

and not

```
stmt=con.prepareStatement(tt);
stmt1.setInt(index1+1,index1*index2);
```

The second code should give compilation error, if this is the complete code you got.

Comment: stmt is probably initialized outside of what the OP posted.

Comment: now getting like this Exception: No value specified for parameter 1